# Generate color scheme with Liferay-theme-task plugin with gulp

Tags: sass, gulp, liferay, liferay-6, liferay-theme

I'm working with the liferay-theme-task plugin, a wonderful tool with gulp to generate Liferay themes. I use Liferay 6.2 with Bootstrap 3, it is not the first project I do and the results are fantastic !!!

The problem I have encountered has been creating the color schemes. I tell you, because it will happen to you:

In the body I catch the look-and-feel  without any problems and I have all the CSS well related to changing color scheme. The problem I have is in my booting aui.css, since when I enter Bootstrap 3 in Liferay I am pulling this css to boot.

Well, I am unable to change my @import"color_schemes/cyan/bootstrap_variables" for each color scheme.

[image: Project with problem]

I only use the first element import variables, if color scheme change ignores me and still showing the same color.

In point 2 I show how I have all the new css of my project related to the color scheme selected in the Liferay configuration. This point does it well, since changing the color scheme in the body gives me its new property.

[image: SCSS Bootstrap Variables]

I have tried it in many ways and there is no way ...

Comment: You say that you're using Liferay 6.2, but you tag Liferay 7. Not that I personally am that well versed in frontend stuff, but this is quite confusing. If you're working with the gulp tasks for Liferay 7 and deploy on Liferay 6.2: I'd not expect that to work.

Comment: The Liferay-theme-task plugin theme generator lets you create and compile both Liferay 6.2 and Liferay 7 themes. This web that I have attached is the same with Liferay 6.2 and Bootstrap 3 with the gulp compiler http://www.giantcement.com @OlafKock

Comment: SO what is exactly the problem? If you check the body tag is the colour class applied? In the aui.css are all the colour variation compiled correctly?

Comment: the problem is that I change color scheme and it takes me the first SCSS file @import "color_schemes / cyan / bootstrap_variables"; In the first one I have a $brand-primary: red and in the second a $brand-primary: green, I only change this color variable. It stays in the red always and when changing of scheme to the green, continue reading red.

Comment: I think you are overriding the same variables. if you have the 2 imports and they have the same variables with different values only the second applies. I think that the scss processing is sequential. Try to move the imports so that they are above the respective sections where they are used.